# Shell Script to Find out Number of occurrences of a substring

Tags: linux, shell

I'm figuring out how to write a shell script to find out the number of occurrences of a sub-string in the main string.

EX.

```
Sample input = abccddccacc 
Enter sub-string=cc 
Sample Output: Number of occurrences =3
```

I understand the basic algorithm but I'm having a hard time coding it in the shell.

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify if *"ccc"* would count as one instance of *"cc"*, or two.  That is, can the substrings overlap?

Comment: I believe that will be 1 instance of cc

Answer (score 0):

For pure `bash` only solution, you can use the match operator in a loop. Overlaps not allowed -- once a match is found it is removed from the source.

```
input=$1    # User input
sub=$2      # Substring to match
i=0
while [[ "$input" = *$sub ]] ; do
    # Remove everything to first match
    input=${input#*$sub}    
    i=$((i+1))
done
echo "REP=$i"
```

Output:

```
owner@vm1:~/Project/stackoverflow/58360772$ ./z.sh abccddccacc c
REP=6
owner@vm1:~/Project/stackoverflow/58360772$ ./z.sh abccddccacc cc
REP=3
owner@vm1:~/Project/stackoverflow/58360772$ ./z.sh abccddccacc ccc
REP=0
```

Does not support "magic" characters, as they will need better quoting/matching.

Answer (score -1):

This function uses *GNU* `grep`; which is cheating, but versatile:

```
count(){ grep -o "$1" | grep -c "$1" ; }
```

Some tests:

```
count cc <<< abccddccacc
man bash | count cc   # input from pipes is OK
count ea < /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/INDEX.txt   # input from a file...
```

Output:

```
3
117
23
```